# What is the meaning and format of LANGUAGE?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, internationalization, locale

I'm used to environment variables such as `LANG` and `LC_*`, but I recently noticed a `LANGUAGE` variable on my Ubuntu desktop. It's value was `pt_BR:pt:en`, and I'm wondering exactly what is meaning is. `LANG`, for one thing, was `pt_BR.UTF-8`, so if that first field is supposed to be the default locale/charset, it was at odds with was `LANG` set.

So, what's the exact meaning and format of `LANGUAGE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LANGUAGE` serves a similar purpose to `LANG` and `LC_MESSAGES` in that it controls what language the user interface is displayed in.

The main difference between them is that while `LANG` and `LC_MESSAGES` can only take a single locale specifier, `LANGUAGE` can take a list of colon separated list of locale specifiers.

As an example, this would allow a user to have programs display in Catalan if available and fall back to Spanish if not before finally falling back to untranslated English, which is not possible with the other variables. In this case would be `LANGUAGE="ca:es:en"` (ISO 639-1 codes).

The other environment variables are set for the benefit of applications not using [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) for translation that only support the older environment variables.

### Reference

- [LANGUAGE variable at GNU](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable)
- [Environment variables at Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#The_LANGUAGE_priority_list)

Answer (score 5):

LANGUAGE determines the order of preference for user interface message localization with gettext. http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable

Comment: Thanks for providing the link to where this is actually defined.